# How to get current JSON object key from JSON array and pass it to another activity in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-json

I want to get current JSON object key from JSON array and  pass it to another activity while Linear Layout OnClick function in android. My JSON array name **extra_info** has three objects inside the **main_header** there is string name of second object, I have to get the second object key pass to the another activity to get fields inside of that object from JSON array .

or else how to find index of current JSON object from JSON array

I have searched many codes but they are provided the all object key of an array.
JSON

```
 "extra_info": [{
             "type": "htmleditor",
             "htmleditor_extra_title": "Key Features",
             "ckeditor_content": ""
         }, {
             "type": "textfield",
             "main_header": "Specifications",
             "field_option": [{
                 "inside_single_title": "General",
                 "basic_opt1": [{
                     "option_name_extra": "Ideal for",
                     "option_desc_extra": "men"
                 }]
             }, {
                 "inside_single_title": "Sandal Details",
                 "basic_opt1": [{
                     "option_name_extra": "Design",
                     "option_desc_extra": "Logo Detail"
                 }, {
                     "option_name_extra": "Closure",
                     "option_desc_extra": "Velcro"
                 }]
             }]
         }, {
             "type": "textfield",
             "main_header": "Sandal Details",
             "field_option": [{
                 "inside_single_title": "General",
                 "basic_opt1": [{
                     "option_name_extra": "Sandal Details",
                     "option_desc_extra": "Sandal Details"
                 }]
             }, {
                 "inside_single_title": "Sandal Details",
                 "basic_opt1": [{
                     "option_name_extra": null,
                     "option_desc_extra": null
                 }]
             }, {
                 "inside_single_title": "Sandal Details",
                 "basic_opt1": [{
                     "option_name_extra": null,
                     "option_desc_extra": null
                 }]
             }]
         }],
```

Code:

```
    specification = alertObj.getJSONArray(SPECIFICATION);
  String spe = String.valueOf(specification);


  System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + specification.length());
  specificationdynamic = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.specfication);
  specifi = new TextView[specification.length()];
  iconimg = new ImageView[specification.length()];

  if (specification.length() > 0) {
      Log.d("specificaiton", String.valueOf(specification.length()));
      int jsoncount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(specification.length()));
      Log.d("specificaiton", String.valueOf(jsoncount));
      for (y = 0; y < specification.length(); y++) {
          specifiobj = specification.getJSONObject(y);
          String speciobj = String.valueOf(specifiobj);
          Log.d("specificaiton", String.valueOf(specifiobj));
          Iterator key = specifiobj.keys();
          while (key.hasNext()) {
              k = key.next().toString();
              System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", value : " +
                  specifiobj.getString(k));
          }
          // System.out.println(objects.toString());
          System.out.println("-----------");



          String types = specifiobj.getString("type");
          if (types.equalsIgnoreCase("textfield")) {
              hori = new LinearLayout(singleshooppingcart.this);
              hori.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
              hori.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
              hori.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
              hori.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 0);
              specifi[y] = new TextView(singleshooppingcart.this);
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0 f);
              params.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

              specifi[y].setLayoutParams(params);
              String main_header = specifiobj.getString("main_header");
              specifi[y].setText(main_header);
              specifi[y].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#151616"));
              specifi[y].setTextSize(18);
              specifi[y].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

              iconimg[y] = new ImageView(singleshooppingcart.this);
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams iconimgs = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              iconimgs.setMargins(0, 0, 23, 0);
              iconimg[y].setLayoutParams(iconimgs);
              iconimg[y].setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp);

              View v = new View(getApplicationContext());
              v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(GetPixel(1, getApplicationContext()), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
              v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
              specifi[y].setText(main_header);

              hori.addView(specifi[y]);
              hori.addView(iconimg[y]);


              v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B3B3B3"));
              specificationdynamic.addView(hori);
              specificationdynamic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View view) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), y, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
              });



          } else {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "statement wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }



      }
```

Anyone Help Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is unclear. please edit it to explain which is the current JSON Object key ?

Comment: what you have try so fart?

Comment: If you want to get a value on click of the view, then you have to set that value in tag.

Comment: I try to get current key of an object using for loop of  json array, but i couldn't get that

Comment: can you pass the value to the another activity ? or you should only pass the key ?

Comment: i want to pass the value of current index object key from json array to another activity

Comment: then use shared preferences to pass the value to another activity

Comment: U didn't understood my question, i want to get index  of current json object from json arry to pass that value to another activity for that why should i use shared preference

Comment: just get the value of index to a variable and pass the variable to another activity.

Comment: i used onclick function for linear layout then how could i get the index for that value

Comment: you want to get the JSONObject value and pass that value to other activity ?

Comment: yes only second jsonobject current key(Main header: specification) want to pass to another activity

Comment: you are getting JSONObject  values ?

Comment: I didn't get u naveen

Comment: you just want to pass the value to anther activity right ?

Comment: i want to passvalue like this jsonarray.opstring(o).jsonobject(currentobject key)

Comment: if you want i will share the code in other way (using shared preferences).

Comment: yes share the code or send me gmail id

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray arraydata = responseObj.getJSONArray("messages");

JSONObject mObject;
for(int i = 0;i<arraydata.length();i++) {
    mObject = arraydata.getJSONObject(i);
    String MESAGE_DATA = mObject.getString("message_data");
    String USER_DATA = mObject.getString("user_data");


    JSONObject JSON_MSG_DATA = new JSONObject(MESAGE_DATA);
    String MSG_ID = JSON_MSG_DATA.getString("message_id");
    String MSG_CUSTM_ID = JSON_MSG_DATA.getString("message_custom_id");
    String MSG_TEXT = JSON_MSG_DATA.getString("message_text");
    String SENDER_ID = JSON_MSG_DATA.getString("sender_id");
    String RECEIVER_ID = JSON_MSG_DATA.getString("receiver_id");
    String MSG_DATE_CREATED = JSON_MSG_DATA.getString("date_created");
    String MSG_DATE_UPDATED = JSON_MSG_DATA.getString("date_updated");
    String PARTNER_ID = JSON_MSG_DATA.getString("partner_id");
    String ELAPSED_TIME = JSON_MSG_DATA.getString("elapsed_time");


    JSONObject JSON_USER_DATA = new JSONObject(USER_DATA);
    String USER_ID = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("user_id");
    String EMAIL = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("email");
    String USERNAME = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("username");
    String PASSWORD = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("password");
    String DEVICE_ID = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("device_id");
    String DEVICE_TYPE = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("device_type");
    String PROFILE_IMAGE = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("profile_image");
    String PHONE = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("phone");
    String GENDER = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("gender");
    String BIO = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("bio");
    String TITLE = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("title");
    String WEB_LINK = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("web_link");
    String STATUS = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("status");
    String USER_DATE_CREATED = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("date_created");
    String USER_DATE_UPDATED = JSON_USER_DATA.getString("date_updated");
}
```

You can fetchdata like this.

Comment: I can't use like this i want to pass object to next activity, so how can i use like this